# update multiple records in elastic using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

Hi guy i have issue with updating multiple records in elastic using logstash.
My logstash configuration is bellow

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "******"
        user => "xxxxx"
        password => "yyyyyy"
        index => "index_name" 
        document_type => "doc_type"
        action => "update"          
        script_lang => "painless"
        script_type => "inline"
        document_id => "%{Id}"
        script => 'ctx._source.Tags = params.event.get("Tags");'
    }
```

}

My output to logstash dump folder looks like:
`{"index_name":"feed_name","doc_type":"doc_type","Id":["b504d808-f82d-4eaa-b192-446ec0ba487f", "1bcbc54f-fa7a-4079-90e7-71da527f56a5"],"es_action":"update","Tags": ["tag1","tag2"]}`

My biggest issue here is that I am not able to update those two recods at once but I need to create two records each with different ID.

Is there a why to solve this by writing query in my output configuration?
In sql that would look someting like this:

```
Update Table 
SET Tags
WHERE ID in (guid1, guid2)
```

I know that in this case I can add two records in logstash and problem solved but I need to solve second issue where I need to replace all records that have one tag1 and give it newTag.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered to use the [*split* filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-split.html) in order to clone the event in events with one *id* each one? It seems the filter can help you.